# RDP on EC2 works until logging out and back in RDP, SSH works without issue - must reboot to get RDP to work again

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a Ubuntu 18.x that I have installed XRDP on and GNOME so I can configure Security Onion 2 for my org. This is a VM running in AWS on a EC2. I have whitelisted my public IP for SSH and RDP in the security groups and local firewall.  At first no issues, I could log in and out via the RDP client on my Mac, but now if I log out or reboot logged in via RDP, I can't RDP back in and the RDP client acts like its unable to find the Ubuntu via its Public IP. Weird thing is I can still SSH into it without issues regardless of what the RDP is telling me. I have confirmed that XRDP is active on startup and the only major change is that I have disabled the compositor for a smoother experience. Like I said, SSH works without issue and the host can be reached no problem, but if I logoff via the GUI through RDP and try to access again via RDP it acts like the host is unreachable. I have to reboot the host to get RDP to work again.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: XRDP is hard to setup for Gnome particularly for Ubuntu 18.04. [Someone has written a script](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17175) that installs and makes the necessary changes. You may give this one a try. As always, you have to be careful with scripts written by strangers. If this works, let me know. I will write an answer you can accept.

Comment: Do not log out once you are in a RDP session and it will work . It looks like you run your xrdp session inside that user gnome session

Comment: I tried the script that was suggested by user68186, will update.

Comment: The script did not work, same behavior as before.